# How to host wcf server on application ?

Tags: wcf

I know how to make wcf service server to run on iis. 
But i need to host my wcf server on something like iis but the service will be available only when my application is up and running.

I know that it is possible to create application that will act like a wcf host.
But in this case i will not have the access from other machine ( right ? ) to this service because as far as i know .. the access to this service from other machine can be done only when the wcf service is running from iis.

Any help please ...
10x

Comment: Does it really need to be a WCF, or could it be a Restful service?
If can call a rest service, you can create a web api service with your application, so your services will be available only when your app is up and you can also call from another application,

Comment: Can you give an example of usage? I am not sure if I clearly understand. Have you considered hosting the service in managed windows service?: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting WCF service has three different types:

- Hosting in [IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Hosting in [Managed Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Hosting in [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx)

> But in this case I will not have the access from other machine ( right
>   ? ) to this service because as far as I know .. the access to this
>   service from other machine can be done only when the WCF service is
>   running from IIS.

If you thought that only the WCF service hosted in IIS is accessible outside that machine where service is hosted. You are completely wrong. As long as your service is up and running and your machine has [Public IP address](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address) you can access it every where.

Comment: 10x - but in case i using managed application - is the access to my wcf service will be use wsdl like on the IIS ? 

Because i want to have wsdl .. is it must to have it only on IIS on this case ?

Comment: All implementation of WCF service is the same no matter where you hosted it.

Comment: 10x again - so i want to be 100% sure that i understand it => on the hosting in managed application - the client will hold wsdl as same as it will have when the hosting in iis ... that what you mean ?